# Next JS 13 not creating export

Tags: next.js

Running `next build` on `"next": "^13.2.4"` does not produce the "export" folder in ".next"

`output: 'export'` set in `next.config.js`

Running `next build` on the canary version produces "export" folder, but with a plethora of errors `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`. JSON nor `parse` is not being used throughout the project at all.

Using App folder structure.

EDIT

`next export` is depriacted in favor of `output: 'export'`. Running it throws: "PageNotFoundError: Cannot find module for page:"

Any ideas for either of the versions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT2

The problem seems to be with the command `"use client"` as removing it seems to solve the issue in some cases. Additionally, NextJS  *apparently* fixed this issue in the latest [release of canary](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases), but Your experience may vary

Comment: run next export to generate folder

Comment: Warning: "next export" is deprecated since Next.js 13.3 in favor of "output: 'export'" configuration as per https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Comment: Are you on Windows? And are you using "use client" in any components? We're having the same issue and it seems to have something to do with "use client" on Windows. Works fine on Linux.

Comment: Yes, Windows. You seem to be on the right track, as removing components with "use client" doesn't throw any errors. Did You manage to come up with any workaround?

Comment: Not yet. And we're using the latest canary version (13.2.5-canary.21).

Comment: This is working for us now on 13.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was fixed in the newest versions of NextJS